# Which is the universally acceptable Video Compression type which should be used in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, c++

Which is the universally acceptable Video Compression type? Can we use `"Microsoft Video1"` `codec` to compress a video in `c#`? Is there any other compression types available which can be used in my `C# code` by default. In my current code I use `AVISaveOptions()` `API` which pops up a dialog box and user selects a `codec` of his choice. Now i do not want to show that popup and just compress the video using any universally acceptable video compressor type.
Please Reply...

Currently I have used the below `c# code` for compressing a video..

```
        Avi.AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS_CLASS opts = new Avi.AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS_CLASS();
        opts.fccType = (uint)Avi.streamtypeVIDEO;

        opts.lpParms = IntPtr.Zero;
        opts.lpFormat = IntPtr.Zero;

        opts.fccType         = (UInt32)Avi.mmioStringToFOURCC("vids", 0);
        opts.fccHandler      = (UInt32)Avi.mmioStringToFOURCC("MSVC", 0);
        opts.dwKeyFrameEvery = 0;
        opts.dwQuality       = 7500;  // 0 .. 10000
        opts.dwFlags         = 8;  // AVICOMRPESSF_KEYFRAMES = 4
        opts.dwBytesPerSecond= 0;
        opts.lpFormat        = new IntPtr(0);
        opts.cbFormat        = 0;
        opts.lpParms         = new IntPtr(0);
        opts.cbParms         = 4;
        opts.dwInterleaveEvery = 0;
```

In this `**(UInt32)Avi.mmioStringToFOURCC("MSVC", 0)**` is used as the Compression type which is `**'Microsoft Video1' codec**.`  Is this compression type works for all windows and other `OS`?  My customer wants a universally acceptable compression format without showing the `AVISaveOptions()` popup dialog.